# creating mobile streaming server (3gp)

Tags: 3gp, helix, helix-dna-server

I need an Open Source solution & tutorial for creating mobile streaming server that can stream video on 3gp (3gpp) format, i have tried using Helix DNA Server, but it's free version only allow real media not 3gp.

I have heard about DSS (Darwin Streaming Server) but i can't found any Windows binaries (compiled exe) for that, and Catra Streaming server package only confused me more since i can't found any file required for Catra (setting, etc are missing on their package).

PS: Actually i need some sort of guide for setting DSS or Catra on Windows (especially Server 2003)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to try [VLC](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/) http://www.videolan.org/vlc/

I can't vouch for the streaming server, but the player works well, and 3gp is supported.

But this isn't a programming question.

Comment: i know this maybe not a programming question, i asked this since i can't found any DSS binaries, which mean i asking for compiled version (which i think related with compiler and programming) LOL, sorry if i ask wrong question.

Gonna try VLC hope it works for streaming 3gp

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

DSS Windows binaries are here:
http://dss.macosforge.org/post/previous-releases/

Answer (score 0):

If you're target mobile devices support flash you can stream 3gp from Red5. If they don't support flash, but they do allow HTML5 you could still use Red5 or pretty much any Java EE container server.